# pyspark trying to retrieve rows having same id

Tags: python, r, hadoop, pyspark

I am using spark 2.1.0. Below is my dataframe. The problem statement is from b column I need to retrieve rows which are having same values in a and different values in b . Resulting dataframe is mentioned

```
a   b

1   2

1   3

1   4

2   6

3   7
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
a b

1 2

1 3

1 4
```

I used the code below but it is not working

```
sqlCtx.sql("select * from df1 group by a,b having count(a)>=2")
```

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: why the result dataframe has 1 only in column a? where are 2 and 3?

Comment: `df.filter($"a" === df.first()(0)).distinct()` should work for your resulting dataframe but first confirm my first comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps!

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
df = sc.parallelize([(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,6), (3,7)]).toDF(["a", "b"])
df.show()
df1 = df.groupBy('a').agg(func.collect_list('b').alias("b_list"),func.count('b').alias("count")).filter(func.col('count') > 1)
df2 = df1.rdd.flatMap(lambda row: [(row.a, b) for b in row.b_list]).toDF(["a", "b"])
df2.show()
```

(**Edit note:** corrected the typo)

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*

Comment: @Naveen if you liked the solution then you should vote up/ accept it as the right answer. It'll surely help others in case they encounter similar problem in future. Thanks!